# Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)\space dx =0$, then $\forall t \in [0,1] : |\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\space dx|\leq1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

> Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable s.t $\forall x \in [0,1]: |f'(x)|\leq8$ . 
> Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)\space dx =0$, then $\forall t \in [0,1] : |\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\space dx|\leq1$.

By Roll's theorem and FTC, I know that $\exists c\in (0,1): f(c) = 0$. 
Moreover,  I deduce that this point $c$ can be chosen such that it is either maximum or minimum of $\tilde{F}$ at $[0,1]$, where $\tilde{F}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(x)\space dx$.

Therefore, my plan was to use the Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange form of the remainder as below:

$\tilde{F}(t) = \tilde{F}(c) + f(c)t + \frac{f'(\xi)}{2!}t^2 = \tilde{F}(c) + \frac{f'(\xi)}{2}t^2$

where $\xi \in (0,1)$. Seemingly this way we're left with terms which can be bounded using the assumptions, however, the bound is bigger than 1.

I'd like to know what I'm missing here, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have done, define $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$.  Then by the given conditions, $F(0)=F(1)=0$. If $F$ is identically zero you have nothing further to prove.  Otherwise let $c$ be the point at which $F$ attains its maximum modulus.  The point $c$ exists because $F$ is continuous and it won't be an end point since $F$ is not identically zero.  Then at $c$, $F'(c) = f(c) = 0$, $F(c)$ being a minimum or maximum.  For $x \in [0,1]$, there exists $\xi$ either in $(x-c,c)$, when $x-c < c$, or in $(c,x-c)$ when $x-c > c$ such that
\begin{align}
 F(x) &= F(c) + (x-c)f(c) +\frac{f'(\xi)}{2!} (x-c)^2 \\
&= F(c) + \frac{f'(\xi)}{2!} (x-c)^2
\end{align}
In either case $\xi \in (0,1)$ and $|f'(\xi)|< 8$.  Now choose $x$ either to be $1$ if $1-c < \tfrac{1}{2}$, or $0$ otherwise.  In either case $F(x) = 0$ and $|x-c| < \tfrac{1}{2}$.  It now follows $0=F(c) + f'(\xi)(x-c)^2/2$, and so,
\begin{align}
|F(c) | &= \frac{|f'(\xi)|}{2}|x-c|^2 \\
&\leq 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ and $m=\max_{0\leq x \leq 1} |F'(x)|$ then using $F(0)=F(1)=0$ we get
$$\frac{F(t)}{t(1-t)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{F(t)}{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{F(t)}{1-t}$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1F'(ut)du-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1F'(1-u(1-t))du$$ which implies that
$$|F(t)|\leq mt(1-t)\leq m/4.$$

We show now that $m\leq 4$ as follows.  For this we write

$$F'(y)=F'(y)-F(1)=\int_0^1(F'(y)-F'(x))dx$$$$=\int_0^y\left(\int_y^xF''(t)dt\right)dx+\int_y^1\left(\int_y^xF''(t)dt\right)dx$$$$\int_0^ytF''(t)dt+\int_0^{1-y}tF''(1-t)dt$$which implies $$|F'(y)|\leq \max_{0\leq t\leq 1}|F''(t)|\times \left(\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{(1-y)^2}{2}\right)\leq \frac{1}{2}\max_{0\leq t\leq 1}|F''(t)|$$ which proves $m\leq 8/2$ as desired.